# numpy.random.exponential(scale=1.0) returns numbers greater than 1

Tags: python, numpy, random, distribution, exponential

Unless I've gone completely insane, the documentation for numpy.random.exponential()

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.exponential.html

suggests that setting the scale parameter to 1.0 should guarantee that function calls return a number between 0.0 and 1.0, since it is only defined for x > 0.

I've graphed it on wolfram alpha to verify I'm not going insane and it does range from 0 to 1.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+exp(-x)+from+-1+to+10

I also tried both numpy.random.exponential() since the default argument is 1.0 and numpy.random.standard_exponential(), but both sometimes give me values greater than 1.

I feel like I've made some silly mistake in my understanding but cannot find it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example code that I ran:

```
import numpy as np
print np.random.exponential(scale=1.0)
```

Example returned value:

```
1.56783951494
```

Answer (score 2):

The exponential function has pdf = 1/beta * exp(-x/beta).  You're passing scale = beta = 1.0, so you have pdf = 1/1 * exp(-x/1) = exp(-x).

This isn't zero above 1.  In fact, you have a 63% chance of getting a number between 0 and 1, and a 37% chance of getting a value above 1:

```
>>> quad(lambda x: np.exp(-x), 0, 1)
(0.6321205588285578, 7.017947987503856e-15)
>>> quad(lambda x: np.exp(-x), 1, np.inf)
(0.3678794411714423, 2.149374899076157e-11)
```

Check:

```
>>> ns = np.random.exponential(scale=1.0, size=10**6)
>>> (ns < 1).mean()
0.63164799999999
```

Now it's true that the **PDF** `exp(-x)` stays between 0 and 1, but that doesn't mean that all the **random numbers drawn** from the distribution will be between 0 and 1.

Think of a die: the chance of any given outcome is 1/6, but every single numeric outcome is >= 1.

Comment: Thanks so much, I misunderstood. It doesn't return the function value, it returns the x.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've realized my stupid mistake. It's not returning f(x, beta) it's returning x. Thank you!